# How can I use docker compose on windows without Docker Desktop

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, visual-studio-2022

I've just unninstalled Docker desktop by reason of its new license terms.

I have already installed docker engine directly into WSL. I'm able to run and manage docker containers but i can't run my composes anymore.

When I tryed to run from inside WSL (from inside my linux instalation), the docker compose command is not recognized.

When I tryed to run from visual studio 2022 (setting docker compose as startup project) I can't even build my solution because some service needed to run my compose is missing since i unninstall docker desktop (Error    MSB4018 The "GetServiceReferences" task failed unexpectedly).

In docs have just instructions to run compose by installing Docker desktop: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/.

Is there another way to run composes in windows without Docker Desktop?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: The Docker Compose plugin was missing in my wsl: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/. It comes built into docker desktop but using wls directly you must install it.

Comment: Thank you sir!..